# AngularJS Linkify cells with links in a table after table has been rendered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I am trying to manipulate the html of a table to replace all text in cells that have links with a `<a>` link that is clickable using AngularJS.

[image]

When the DOM is loaded I have the following code:

```
...
$("td").each(function (index) {
  if($(this).text())
  {
      $(this).text($ctrl.linkify($(this).text().toString()));
  }
});
...

$ctrl.linkify = function(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
         return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}
```

However it doesn't render the links as clickable link elements.

[image]

An important note is that the table is added dynamically by a third party plugin so I can only manipulate it **after** it has loaded. Hence why in the title I mentioned after the table has been rendered.

How can I use angular js to linkify the cells? Or use sanitize to render the new html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing it as text **because ng-model or {{}} shows only text**, you need to show them as html and in this case **you can use ngBingHtml directive.** 
To use it, you must include into your project angular-sanitize and after it in your table you can use in this way:

Here a working example

```js
var editor = angular.module("editor",['ngSanitize']);
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['editor']);


editor.controller('EditorController', function($scope) {

    $scope.values = ['Normal text', 
                     'https://www.google.com/', 
                     'This is not a link'];
    $scope.replaceUrlWithATag = function(text){
      var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      return text.replace(urlRegex, (url) => {return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>'});
    }
});


editor.directive("editorView",function(){
  return {
    restrict :"EAC",
    templateUrl : "editor.html",
    scope : {
        content : "=editorView"
    },
    link : function(scope,element,attrs){
        
    }
  };
});

app.controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = 'World';});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="EditorController">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="v in values">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td ng-bind-html="replaceUrlWithATag(v)"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```